# Reactjs Filter by Category, Brand ,Type

Tags: reactjs

I want to filter my product by category, type, and brand. I found a video from youtube and follow the tutorial but I only can filter by category or type or brand at once time, and also if after I click on "Filter by Category "test" then I click on other filter it display nothing.

ScreenShot of my website

[image: 1]

My code

`

```
        const filterResult = (catItem) => {
        const result = product.filter((product) => {
            return product.category === catItem
        });
        setProduct(result);
        }

        <div>
            <h3 onClick={ () => {filterResult('test')}}>Filter by Category "test"</h3>
            <h3 onClick={ () => {filterResult('abc')}}>Filter by Category "abc"</h3>
            <h3 onClick={ () => {filterResult('efg')}}>Filter by Category "efg"</h3>
            <h3 onClick={ () => {filterResult('belden')}}>Filter by Brand "belden"</h3>
            <h3 onClick={ () => {filterResult('bluguard')}}>Filter by Brand "bluguard"</h3>
            <h3 onClick={ () => {filterResult('audio')}}>Filter by Type "audio"</h3>
            <h3 onClick={ () => {filterResult('wifi ')}}>Filter by Type "wifi"</h3>
            <h3 onClick={lowToHigh}>Sort By Low to High</h3>
            <h3 onClick={highToLow}>Sort By High to Low</h3>
         </div>
```

So how do I filter my product by category, type and brand at same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put the filters into state. Either have a different state for each possible filter, or use a single state with an object. Then use that state as the basis for the filtered products.

You probably don't want to do `setProduct(result);`, because that'll overwrite the existing state; you won't be able to get back to the original products. Instead of having a state for the filtered products, filter them when rendering.

```
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
  category: '',
  brand: '',
  type: '',
});
const makeFilter = (property, newFilterValue) => () => {
  setFilters({
    ...filters,
    [property]: newFilterValue,
  });
};
```

The utility function `makeFilter` above makes it easy to concisely create a click handler that adds a filter.

```
<h3 onClick={makeFilter('category', 'test')}>Filter by Category "test"</h3>
<h3 onClick={makeFilter('category', 'abc')}>Filter by Category "test"</h3>
```

And to render:

```
products // original state
  .filter(prod =>
    prod.category.includes(filters.category) &&
    prod.brand.includes(filters.brand) &&
    prod.type.includes(filters.type)
  )
  .map(product => // JSX to render product, as desired
```